# Mass density of dark matter in solar system near us

Tags: astrophysics, solar-system, dark-matter

What is the approximate mass density of dark matter in our solar system at the radius of the Earth's orbit?

I would like some idea of the mass of dark matter going through each cubic meter of material on earth.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56141/why-is-the-dark-matter-density-profile-within-the-solar-radius-and-local-densit?rq=1

Comment: Actually after surfing the net it looks like the density of dark matter in the center of the milky way is about 1 proton mass per cc.

Comment: Well, let's at least word this as "theoretical localized dark mass density," since we don't yet know if there is such a thing, or where/how it exists.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Constraints on Dark Matter in the Solar System](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5534) the following upper limits have been placed on dark matter in the solar system, based upon orbital motion of bodies in the solar system:

At the radius of Earth's orbit:
$1.4 \times 10^{-19} \mathrm{g/cm^3}$

At the radius of Mars's orbit:
$1.4 \times 10^{-20} \mathrm{g/cm^3}$

At the radius of Saturn's orbit:
$1.1 \times 10^{-20} \mathrm{g/cm^3}$

According to [Local Density of Dark Matter](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3670), the density of dark matter at the Sun's location in the galaxy is $0.43 \,\mathrm{GeV/cm^3}$ or $7.7 \times 10^{-25} \mathrm{g/cm^3}$

Comment: With error bars (adding uncertainties in quadrature) it is $(0.4\pm 0.1)$GeV/cm$^3$.

Comment: Or in other words, roughly 400 thousand protons' mass of dark matter per cubic meter or about half a proton's mass per cubic centemeter.

Answer (score 0):

Density of dark matter in the Sun's orbit (Sun rotates with speed υ ≈ 220 km/s at a
distance r = $2.57\times 10^{20}$ m from center of Milky Way ): 
ρ☼=$8.737\times 10^{−22}$ $kg/m^3$ = $78.5\ \mu J /m^3$ or 522000 protons/m$^3$.
To learn more, you can find in mini-novel "Flippon" at the Flippin Theory website: http://www.science.uwaterloo.ca/~kdvorski/TheFlippingTheoryWebSite/pdf/Flippon-First%20Edition.pdf